# DataGridView.DataSource not binding three or more datagridview together

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, bindingsource

I have 3 `DataGridView` as follows

1. dataGridViewTASKLIST
2. dataGridView_USER_ROLES
3. dataGridViewProjects

These 3 grids are used for different purposes. I am trying to bind (using BindingSource) data from 3 different Tables, Table1, Table2, Table3 (Inside database ) using sqlDataAdapter and DataTable. After running the program only the first grid ( dataGridViewTASKLIST ) is getting filled with rows and columns and the remaining two grids are  empty.

My code is as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine("Binding 1st Grid");
BindingSource bn = new BindingSource();

bn.DataSource = this.dbCommon.getDataTableAsResult("select * from taskTable");
dataGridViewTASKLIST.DataSource = bn;

Console.WriteLine("Binding 2nd Grid");
BindingSource bn1 = new BindingSource();

bn1.DataSource = this.dbCommon.getDataTableAsResult("select * from userTable");
dataGridView_USER_ROLES.DataSource = bn1;

Console.WriteLine("Binding 3rd Grid");
BindingSource bn2 = new BindingSource();

bn2.DataSource = this.dbCommon.getDataTableAsResult("select * from projectTable");
dataGridViewProjects.DataSource = bn2;
```

where dbCommon is the object of class DatabaseClass and getDataTableAsResult() is a method inside the databaseClass

```
public DataTable getDataTableAsResult(string cmd)
{
    sqlDatatable = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        if (this.openConnection())
        {
            sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, this.sqlConn);
            sqlAdapter.Fill(sqlDatatable);
        }

     }
     catch { }
     finally
     {
        this.closeConnection();
     }
     return sqlDatatable;
}
```

Comment: Inorder to debug better, can you try assigning the return value from getDataTableAsResult method to a variable and checking if the right data is returned in the first place?

Comment: @Mohamed Najiullah  the return value is correct and if i wrote datagridview2.datasource= .. instead of datagridview1.datasource ( i mean if i change the binding order of datagridviews) the datagridview2 will get filled and datagridview1 and 3 will be empty. means it will not contain any values even headers.

Comment: It mean the error is in your `getDataTableAsResult` method. Probably `openConnection` returns false or `Fill` throws an exception for next commands.

Comment: Could you post the code for `this.openConnection` and `this.closeConnection()` as well?

Comment: @jstreet I don't think that is the problem since `sqlDatatable` is instantiated every time `getDataTableAsResult` is called. I think Reza's comment makes sense.

Comment: Solved! Thank you peoples! Problem when sql connection gets closed after executing 1st grid !